# There was no endpoint listening at <url> - SharePoint 2013 Provider-hosted App, AppEventReceiver

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am trying to deploy a SharePoint 2013 Provider-hosted App in one of our servers. The SharePoint farm and the remote web service are installed on the same server, but in different IIS websites/applications.

The app is configured to handle the app installed event and to call the remote event on the same server. I am getting the following error when I try to install the app:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://services.somecompany.com/someapp/services/AppEventReceiver.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action

I have configured the endpoint in the web.config (see below) for the service and I am able to access the service by typing the url in IE address bar. I can also get the WSDL for the service. The service website is configured to accept Windows authentication in IIS.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WindowsAuth">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="SomeService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpEndpoint" contract="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers.IRemoteEventService"/>
      <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Is there some other detail I am missing in the configuration? Has anyone come across this situation before and has the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

With

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

This is just because you are using HTTPS...